# Will class method referencing the class instance but not via self cause circ dependency, and how to fight it?

Tags: python, circular-dependency

if class B is a child of A, would the following code cause circular dependency?
(I don't make difference between A, B, and A(), B() for simplicity)

```
def random_function(B):
    # get parent
    par = B.A

    do_stuff(par, B)   



class A:

    def method(self):
        # get B
        b = A.B
        random_function(b)
        # random_function will reference A now, but not via self, is this a problem?
```

I know, that is easily solved with

```
def random_function(A,B):
    do_stuff(A, B)   



class A:

    def method(self):
        # get B
        b = A.B
        random_function(self, b)
```

... but I wonder whether I can still keep the signature with only one argument.

if this is too abstract, here is why I am asking: in Blender, there is a socket class and a node class, with sockets being children of a node. I have a subclass of node and a function like follows:

```
def func(socket):
    # get parent
    node = socket.node
    do_stuff(node, socket)

class sub_class(Node):

    def method(self):
        func(self.Socket)
```

is there a way to keep the function signature with only one argument and not run into circular dependency here?

EDIT: an edit to supply some actual code and context, following suggestions in comments

I'll start with the description of the classes that, as I believe, are causing the circular reference.

Class **`ShaderNodeCustomGroup`** represents a node - a thing from visual programming. It has sockets and it's listetning to what is happening on those sockets. User connects inputs to input sockets, can get output from output sockets. Basically a visual representation of a function for non-programming users. Unreal has this as well, but mine is from Blender.

Class **`Socket`**, already mentioned above - this is what can take input and what gives you output.

I do not know, how exactly they interact - that's defined in source code, and I am just using API but somehow I crash entire application if I do the following:

function causing the crash:

```
def get_socket_neighbor(socket, offset):
    """
        get the neighbor of this socket, whose position is specified by the offset
        RETURNS: a socket or OUT_OF_RANGE
        NOTE: offset is not for the Blender socket order, it's acual movement by 'offset' socket up or down in world coordinates
    """
    sock_ind = get_socket_index(socket, socket.node)
    desired_position = sock_ind - offset # <--- the actual position in 'blender coordinates'
    if desired_position > (len(socket.node.inputs)-1) or desired_position < 0:
        return OUT_OF_RANGE
    else: 
        return socket.node.inputs[desired_position]
```

This one, for a socket in a node, finds its neighbor: for example, a socket one position up, or one position down (see the illustration for nodes and sockets, sockets are the small circles). What it does, it takes a socket, gets the node, to which it belongs, deduces the position of the socket (**`sock_ind = get_socket_index(socket, socket.node)`**), and returns a neighbor socket.

Now, I construct a subclass of **`ShaderNodeCustomGroup`** (in the following SUBCLASS). This subclass can spawn its UI and have sockets and do all the stuff that a node can do. It just has several additional features that I can define. From this class's method, the above function is called. SUBCLASS gives one of its sockets as input to this function. The function is then getting the socket's node (this is simply SUBCLASS itself). This crashes the application.

```
class LayerStackNode(bpy.types.ShaderNodeCustomGroup):
            bl_label = "Layer Stack"

       .
       .
       .

        def insert_link(self, link):
    # runs on the insert of a link,
    # this is a preferred method when
    # it gets repaired by blender devs

        # check if the user is connecting mask
        if link.to_socket.name == "mask_layer":
            # simply draw a link from this socket to its mixer
            my_index = mf.get_socket_index(link.to_socket, self)
            relevant_layer = mf.get_socket_neighbor(link.to_socket, 1)
            relevant_mixer = mf.get_node_by_type(self.node_tree.nodes, 'GROUP_INPUT').outputs[my_index - 1].links[0].to_node
            self.node_tree.links.new(relevant_mixer.inputs[0], mf.get_node_by_type(self.node_tree.nodes, 'GROUP_INPUT').outputs[my_index])
            return

        def is_insert_input(self, link): 
        # determines whether the iserted link is input
            if link.to_socket.name == 'layer':
                return True
            else:
                return False

        if not is_insert_input(self, link):
            return  

        # if trying to insert on top of an empty layer, cancel and return
        if mf.get_socket_neighbor(link.to_socket, -1) != mf.OUT_OF_RANGE and \
            mf.get_socket_neighbor(link.to_socket, -1).is_NULL_layer:
            # TODO: find a way to undo the operation
            return

        if self.is_NULL_layer(link.to_socket): # proceed only if it's empty
            if not mf.get_socket_index(link.to_socket, self) == (len(self.inputs)-1): # <--- private case for the lowest layer in the stack
                if not self.is_NULL_layer(mf.get_socket_neighbor(link.to_socket, -1)):
                    self.initialize_layer(link.to_socket)
                else:
                    print("CANNOT MIX ONTO NULL LAYER")
            else:
                # when base layer, create a single link from input to output
                sock_index = mf.get_socket_index(link.to_socket, self)
                out = mf.get_node_by_type(self.node_tree.nodes, 'GROUP_INPUT').outputs[sock_index]
                inp = mf.get_node_by_type(self.node_tree.nodes, 'GROUP_OUTPUT').inputs[0]
                self.node_tree.links.new(inp, out)
        else:
            print("no action needed, the layer is not NULL") 

       .
       .
       .
```

Relevant for you is `mf.get_socket_neighbor(link.to_socket, -1).is_NULL_layer`.
Here the class of the node gives one if its sockets to the function, and it then tries to find the node of this socket, which is the calling class itself.

To sum up, SUBCLASS's method gives SUBCLASS's socket to a function, which then is trying to access the socket's node, which is SUBCLASS itself. If I rebuild the code, so that the function simply takes self, and does not have to access socket.node, everything works.

So, my question is: is this circular reference? If yes, are there ways to overcome it? I do care because that makes using classes less sensible: for example, I cannot define a property of socket which accesses its node. Because if I use this property from inside a node method, this will crash application as well.

Comment: I applaud you taking another chance at this.  I will look at it tomorrow. - I liked your idea of keeping it simple with a symbolic example.  Maybe you could try that again, but try to embody the problem you think you have in terms of parent/child, circular reference, etc.  If you could explain where you see the problem when actually following the execution flow, that would be great.  I don't want to criticize your first attempt and then not help you all that I can.  I actually feel I need to do this.  Computers have been good to me.  Want to give back.

Comment: ...I might need you to take me through this a bit.

Comment: @Steve sounds great, thanks. if you have questions on the underlying classes and blender api, please feel free to ask. okay, I'll make several edits to that in a while, and then you can ask what's still missing, cheers!

Comment: @Steve I've made a massive edit but no chance to make it comprehensible to any extent, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

There is no parent/child relationship here, either explicitly shown or implied.  B.A and A.B do not suggest parent/child relationships.  They just say that B contains an attribute name 'A' and A contains an attribute named 'B'.  There's nothing wrong with this at all (naming conventions aside).  The two names have nothing to do with each other, nor do they have anything to do with a parent/child relationship. In the case of B.A, the 'A' has nothing to do with the class named 'A'.

Regarding:

```
# random_function will reference A now, but not via self, is this a problem?
```

no, random_function will not reference A.  random_function will reference whatever the A class's B attribute contains.

Comment: I think you're right about there being no parent/child relationship. Also, `random_function()` is referencing the `A` attribute of whatever was argument was passed to it as its `B` _parameter_ — which might not be a class at all.

Comment: Right.  With this code, you don't know much at all about what's going on.  This code, all by itself, would of course not run.  For it to run, the 'B' attribute of A would have to be defined, and whatever that is, it would have to have an attribute named 'A'.

Comment: Yes, it's unclear exactly what the OP is asking — which is why I've refrained from trying to answer it myself (and why I said "think" in my previous comment).

Comment: I felt I could say something because it seems clear that the OP thinks that A.B and B.A somehow denote parent/child relationships.  I just wanted to point out that that wasn't true.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I have mentioned explicitely at the beginning that B is a class. A is defined in the code, hence it's a class as well. actually, this is crashing the application upon running. sorry for the abstract code, I will ammend it in a while

Comment: @Steve "no, random_function will not reference A. random_function will reference whatever the A class's B attribute contains." not only that. b is accessing A from inside the function, isn't it? I don't know, what you call it, but it crashes the application.

Comment: I added some code but I don't think it will be helpful in any way. if you do say that the initial code is completely okay, then this may be an issue with Blender API.

Comment: "b is accessing A from inside the function, isn't it?" - do you mean B.A in the function?  If so, then no, that 'A' has nothing to do with the class A.  B.A could be pointing to an instance of class A, which is maybe what you mean, but there's no way to know what that actually means unless you show us.  In B.A, 'A' is just an arbitrary name. What we need really something that actually runs and shows the problem...a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If we could take the code from your question, run it, and see this crash you talk about, that would be the ideal.  Can you create that?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but none of your initial question gave us anything to work with.  I tried to understand it.  There was nothing there that I could make any sense of to give you any help, or I would have.  I'm guessing that that's why your question was downvoted.  Try to produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Try to form a question with code that can actually run on its own, even if it requires packages to be installed.  I don't think this is a Blender issue, at least yet.  I still have no idea what you're asking, and I'm a seasoned veteran. I want to help.  Promise.

Comment: @Steve didn't see your last comments. If I reproduce the situation in a simple script, you will be able to run it in Blender and see the problem? If so, then I am going to do that